# @Autowired with @Qualifier not working if using (required=false) with autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am trying to use @Autowired with @Qualifier having required=false in Autowired annotation like this

```
@Autowired(required=false)
@Qualifier("myValidator")
private MyValidatorClass validator;
```

If I am not initializing this particular bean in context xml file,then it should not give error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myValidator' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeanByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:526)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
... 39 more
```

According to my business requirement,I want both annotations on the property.I am new to spring, please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Can you show your `MyValidatorClass`, including annotations?

Comment: I think...You forgot to add @Service or @Component annotation on class level in `MyValidatorClass`

Comment: You will still need a qualifying bean even if you set `required=false`

Comment: Why I have to set ? ....then what is the use of required=false

Comment: @Nitika it is already having Component annotation